# Gitlab regex not working in needs keyword

Tags: regex, gitlab-ci

I'm not sure if I'm the problem or if `needs:ref` is the issue.

I have a job that should download artifacts from another job in a different repo. The ref I'm trying to match on is a tag named "v0.1.1-dev.3".

```
my-job:
  stage: build
  script:
  # does stuff
  needs:
    - project: my-group/my-project
      job: my-other-job-in-another-repo
      ref: /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-dev\.[0-9]+$/
      artifacts: true
```

The main problem is that the regex refuses to match in `needs:ref`, but it's the exact same regex that I use in `my-other-job-in-another-repo` in the `only` keyword.

```
my-other-job-in-another-repo:
  stage: build
  script:
  # does stuff
  only:
    - /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-dev\.[0-9]+$/
```

However, this does work for whatever reason.

```
my-job:
  stage: build
  script:
  # does stuff
  needs:
    - project: my-group/my-project
      job: my-other-job-in-another-repo
      ref: v0.1.1-dev.3
      artifacts: true
```

Does anyone know why the regex doesn't work in `needs:ref`, but it works fine with the literal string?

Comment: From the docs, I gather this needs GitLab premium. And I doubt it supports regular expressions for `ref`. I assume only a specfic ref can be provided (I don't find any needs:ref: regex example is the docs either) – you are trying to download _one_ artifact of the latest job run for a ref. Which artifact do you expect to be downloaded if multiple refs match your regex?

Comment: I would presume the most recent, successful run of the specified job with that tag would be the behavior. The same question could be asked if the ref is the branch name though. Even when I switch the ref to the branch - named 'dev' in this instance - it refuses to download the artifacts, even though both the head of 'dev' and the tag both point to the exact same commit.

Comment: Do you have GitLab premium? Does it work with tags? The docs even use branch "main" as an example.

Comment: No I just use the free version. It does work with tags. I figured that regexs would work because they work in other things, such as `only` and `needs`, but it sounds like I'm wrong so I can always just restructure the repo to make gitlab do what I want.

Comment: as written in my first comment: cross-project artifact download with `needs:` requires _GitLab premium_ – see [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cross-project-artifact-downloads-with-needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GitLab 14.0 docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cross-project-artifact-downloads-with-needs), cross-project artifact download with the `needs:` keyword is only supported in GitLab Premium or higher tiers.

The documentation doesn't mention `needs:ref:` supporting globs or wildcards. I can't say for sure, but I assume only a single ref is supported, otherwise GitLab would be unable to pick the "right" artifact to download (latest job of all matching ref? latest job of the first matching ref? latest job of the matching ref with the newest commit?)